# Проседает по времени при апдейте документа

Tags: c#, mongodb

Есть коллекция в Монго, сейчас в ней 227750 документов. Сигнатура документа такая:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c5d4c3a086dad5e5ab8d397"),
    "Uid" : "SomeiDString",
    "SomeTextField" : "SomeText"
}
```

индексы - два поля:

```
{
    "v" : 2,
    "key" : {
        "_id" : 1
    },
    "name" : "_id_",
    "ns" : "db.mycollection"
},
{
    "v" : 2,
    "unique" : true,
    "key" : {
        "Uid" : 1.0
    },
    "name" : "Uid_1",
    "ns" : "db.mycollection",
    "background" : true
}
```

В шарпе выполняю асинхронный UpdateOneAsync, по фильтру Uid, апдейчу "SomeTextField".

```
private async Task < bool > PutSomeTextMongoDb(string Uid, string SomeText) {
  var collection = database.GetCollection < User > (MONGO_DB_COLLEСTION);
  var filter = Builders < User > .Filter.Eq("Uid", Uid);
  var update = Builders < User > .Update.Set("SomeText", SomeText);
  var option = new UpdateOptions {
    IsUpsert = true
  };
  var result = await collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update, option);
  return result.ModifiedCount != 0;
}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что на 5000 запрсов среднее время выполнения всякой логической обработки и записи в монго хорошо 2-3 мс, но у некоторых обращений в монгу время заметно вырастает - запрос на добавление в монгу и получение от неё ответа доходит до 1000 мс. С чем может быть это связано? Может ли быть какой-то lock при апдейте, или может когда монга делает flush на диск, там копится некая очередь?

mongostat и mongotop ответов не дали...

Comment: в вопросе недостаточно вводных, чтобы дать ответ. можно только предполагать

Comment: @Anatol предположения тоже будет - хорошо. Если бы было больше информации, прослеживалось зависимостей и тд и тп, я бы это добавил. но я не знаю в какую сторону копать.
пробовал поиграть с конфигами клиента монги в mongo driver, поменять пулсайзы минимальные/максимальные, но проблема остаётся.